# mod_jk - 2 JkMount Directives with the same URL but different workers

Tags: apache-2.2, apache-2.4, httpd, mod-jk

I have a question. How would the following mod_jk directives be interpreted?

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName backend.example.com

  ...
  JkMount /api/prod     worker1
  JkMount /api/prod/*   worker1

  JkMount /api/prod     worker2
  JkMount /api/prod/*   worker2
  ...

</VirtualHost>
```